# Paypal payment page layout broken in webview android

Tags: android, paypal, webview

I am facing a strange issue on  some android devices, I am opening the paypal payment page on webview and it's layout get broken on some devices.

Please anyone have any idea , Please suggest,  i am stuck
This screenshot device's browser was chrome version 34.0.1847.114
But earlier on this device this page was opening properly

Please help guys

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution here?

Comment: @Er.KT no it happens randomly on some device and user is not able to use the paypal payment

Comment: so what you did to fix that? anyway its fixed in my case but now in webview am not able to see creditcard option,any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

> [Paypal payment page layout broken in webview android maybe css not loaded correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326407/paypal-payment-page-layout-broken-in-webview-android-maybe-css-not-loaded-correc/24338026#24338026)

I came across this problem only in the sandbox environment.

You should try it in the product environment instead. Maybe every freak problems will be gone.