# Paypal payment page layout broken in webview android maybe css not loaded correctly?

Tags: android, paypal, webview

As kadhirvel mentioned in his ask ([Paypal payment page layout broken in webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405919/paypal-payment-page-layout-broken-in-webview-android))

And this (https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/paypal-Android-webview-layout-issue-on-payment-page/td-p/807164).

We both can't load paypal payment page correctly, but messy layout showed up.

I guess that if css files cannot be loaded or some other questions.

I also come with this problem.

Can any one do me a favor?

PS: I'm in China, and the page of Alipay can showed up correctly but paypal.

Comment: Hey treemanz maybe using the https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK might be an option for you? You don't have to implement webview for paypal? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299417/getting-result-back-of-webview-operation/24309938?noredirect=1#comment37591992_24309938

Comment: Thx for your comment. But we have develop the whole website, so we hope to solve this problem in order to reuse our website, instead of developing with PayPal-Android-SDK. Now I try to use the native webview instead of the one cutomized by me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the SSL check your browser security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!

It's because of the f*cking sandbox environment of paypal...

When in sandbox, and using webview to load the page, you will get into this problem.

When in the product env, every strange problems are gone!